# What GA APIs to use for customer interaction raw data access?

Tags: azure, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I need to retrieve Customer's raw data from Google Analytics or use an API. I am not sure which API would give all of customers interactions on the site. I have to load this data on Azure data lake for advanced reporting. Also, where does the actual data reside? Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw data can be exported in BigQuery. The link to BQ is currently free for GA4 Property while for Universal Analytics you must have the GA360 paid plan.
You can get data with API as well but not raw.

Comment: We got license now for GA 360. Now, I have to figure out which API's to use.

Comment: I was able to export raw data from GA 360. Ref: [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-export-data-from-google-analytics-4-to-google-bigquery-5694a71fcb25) - Then make API call to get raw data - [link](https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-streaming-api-with-postman-51516afe4da2)